# How can i get value of datepicker

Tags: c#, uwp

I would get date value of my datepicker.

View :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Command="{Binding RecuperationDateTime}" Content="Retour" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,567,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <DatePicker Name="heurePicker" Date="{Binding SerieEnCours.RecupHeure}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,331,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 </Grid>
```

ViewModel :

```
`public RelayCommand RecuperationDateTime{ get; private set; }

 private lenovo serieEnCours;

    public lenovo SerieEnCours
    {
        get
        {
            return serieEnCours;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != serieEnCours)
            {
                serieEnCours = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public VM_lenvo(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        SerieEnCours = new lenovo()
        {
            TarifEnCours = 0,
            RecupHeure = DateTime.Now
        };

        _navigationService = navigationService;
        RecuperationDateTime= new RelayCommand(_RecuperationDateTime);
    }

    private void _RecuperationDateTime()
    {
        DateTime heure = SerieEnCours.RecupHeure;
        //Return
        _navigationService.GoBack();
    }`
```

Modele :

```
 DateTime HeureRecuperer;
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 public DateTime RecupHeure
 {
    get
            {
                return HeureRecuperer;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != HeureRecuperer)
                {
                    HeureRecuperer = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RecupHeure"));
                    }
                }
           }
        }
```

When i generate my code, i have an "error".
I get my actually date...

Comment: *"When i generate my code, i have an "error""* Would help us greatly if you tell us what this "error" is.

Comment: when i say "error", it's not Visual Studio. Just the fact of i don't get my value of datepicker but actually date

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let user select a date, you will have to use `TwoWay` data binding:

```
{Binding SerieEnCours.RecupHeure, Mode=TwoWay}
```

By default the binding only observes the changes in the view model and transmits them to the UI, but not the other way around. When you add `TwoWay` mode, it will also reflect UI changes in view model.

Comment: `<DatePicker Name="heurePicker" Date="{Binding SerieEnCours.RecupHeure,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,331,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>` 
I have edit but i didn't get my date selected